# SvcTraceViewer not showing exceptions in red

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, logging, trace

the problem is that activities from my web service with exceptions are not showing up in red in SvcTraceViewer. example:

```
throw new Exception("No hello to you!");
```

shows up in SvcTraceViewer as (the lines in red are about service binding mismatches. maybe because i'm using WcfTestClient, but it still seems to work):

[image]

but it is supposed to be red, according to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe

```
"Activities that contain warning traces have a yellow background 
and those that contain error traces have a red one."
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\tmp\log\Web_messages.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="C:\tmp\log\Web_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

- any ideas what the problem could be?
- am i misinterpretting the
  documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems only part of exception will show red, for example unable to connect to remote server.

When I add diagnostics at client side and close the server, error will show in log.
But when I throw an exception in server side , it will generate another log file with random file name.

Below is the snapshot for auto generated file 11360b4c-3ea3-47fa-85d5-12c313bb55b4temp.svclog
[image]

Comment: i'm only logging server-side. you are probably getting random file names because the log file is locked. i'm trying to get an idea of how usable SvcTraceViewer is for normal users